# How to select elements by name and a value check with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-selectors

I'm completely new on JQuery and not so used to JavaScripting yet.

I have a form with named (attribute 'name') elements that I need to process one by one. I also want to update their class attribute if they are validated correctly.

I collected all the form elements with:

```
var Form = $('#'+fChildID).closest('form')[0];
var Element;

if (Form) {
  for(var n=0; n<Form.length; n++) {
    Element = Form.elements[n];
.
// Do some processing and validation
.
    // Update the element's class attribute
    $('*[name="'+Element.name+'"]').addClass("boxselected");
  }
}
```

What I want to do is to use the function .addClass on the Element object, but it seems like JQuery always needs a selector and can't operate directly on an object.

It seems to be that it would be unnecessary to use the * selector when I already have the Element object in a variable.

Can I also use the selector to check if certain attributes (plural) in the same element has specific values?

Comment: Could you make a short summary? In one sentence: for which elements you want the addClass to be applied to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use the element as the argument to the $ function, no other selector needed if you already have the element.

```
$(Element).addClass('boxselected');
```

If you want to check for attribute values you can use `filter`.

```
$(Element).filter('[type=radio][value="yes"]').addClass('boxselected');
```